# Is there a way to map controllers to every url in my web application?

Tags: spring, forms, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal, request-mapping

The spring documentation says that if you don't annotate the controller to a certain url it should be absolute, which I thought to mean the controllers would then apply to every page, is this correct? When I try removing all of my mapping annotations then I get an ambiguous mapping error. I am specifically working with thymeleaf. I have some forms that are modals but right now they will only pop up on the specific url and I want them to be usable on every page of the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all the mapping annotations then all the forms have the same URL. Spring does not know which form to return and throws an "ambiguous mapping error". If you want to have reuseable some common parts of the site you can use Thymeleaf fragments.

Comment: Thank you! How would i annotate a controller for a form that is used in fragments?